# Randrange whitin static method

Tags: python

I wrote a method (in Python) `get_16bit_error` for generate a random integer of 16 bits. I'm trying to understand why this code always output "similar" numbers. For an instance when I ran this code two times I obtained 0x10000, 0x100000 or 0x800000, 0x8000000.

```
class Util(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_16bit_error():
        i = randrange(0, 16)
        e = bin(2 ** i)[2:]
        len_e = len(e)
        e = "0"*(16 - len_e) + e
        return int(e + "0"*(16), 2)
for i in range(2):
    print hex(Util.get_16bit_error())
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit is a binary digit, so 16 bits is 16 binary digits.

```
import random

class Util(object):

    @staticmethod
    def get_16bit_error():
        string = ''
        for i in range(16):
            string += random.choice(['1', '0'])
        return '0b' + string


the_binary = hex(Util.get_16bit_error())
in_decimal = print int(the_binary, 2)

print the_binary # or in_decimal
```

Answer (score 0):

You're generating numbers of the form `2**(16 + randrange(0,16))`. I'm guessing that's not what you want. Let's break it down:

```
i = randrange(0, 16)
```

`i` is a random number between 0 and 16. Good so far. Let's proceed assuming `i = 3`.

```
e = bin(2 ** i)[2:]
```

So now you've exponentiated `2` by `i` (in our example, `2**i = 8`. Then you convert it to binary representation and take the back end of the string, so `e = 1000`.

```
len_e = len(e)
```

The length of `e`, which is `4` in our example.

```
e = "0"*(16 - len_e) + e
```

This essentially pads `e` with zeros so that it has length 16. In our example, `e = '0000000000001000'`.

```
return int(e + "0"*(16), 2)
```

First you add sixteen zeros to the end of the binary representation. This has the effect of taking what *was* `2**i` and making it `2**(16 + i)`. You then convert it to an integer. That's why all your hex representations look the same.

If you want to generate a random 16 bit number, try this:

```
import random
def rand_16_bit_int():
    return random.randrange(2**16)
```

Lastly, I'm not sure what the purpose of the `Util` class and the `staticmethod` is here... perhaps you're coming from Java where you have to put all your methods in classes. Not so in python. It's sufficient to define `rand_16_bit_int` as a free function in your module.